# Python (Pyside) connect() arguments syntax

Tags: python, function, pyside

I am new to PySide and Python in general.
I came across this following function in the PySide docs:

```
Signal.connect(receiver[, type=Qt.AutoConnection])
```

Can anyone explain to me what the function/argument part above means ?

Comment: Also the 'receiver' argument, is supposed to be a callable as mentioned in the docs

Comment: And are you familiar with Qt signals? This API merely implements that concept in Python code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is documenting that the `type` keyword argument to the `Signal.connect()` method is optional. When `type` is omitted, it defaults to `Qt.AutoConnection`.

The `receiver` positional argument is required.

You can use any callable for the `reciever`; it'll simply be called with no arguments in that case. You may want to decorate the callable with the [`Slot`](https://deptinfo-ensip.univ-poitiers.fr/ENS/pyside-docs/PySide/QtCore/Slot.html) decorator.

PySide `Slot` objects are direct analogies of the [PyQT New-style Signal and Slot Support](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html).